# Making partitions visible. Doesn't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, bios, boot-partition

I can't see partitions I make on my external HDD when I boot, after making changes with GParted and even the installer (from live USB). I think I did the configuration right as I set up the space for Linux as Primary ext4 journaling system with mount point / and the Swap Space as Primary too. I believe I need to work with BIOS and such stuff now...

I have read around the net for stuff but it's stuffy, going into terminal commands and checks. Could use something more precise. I am not good with terminal at all. At least some links or something would help...

Comment: Have you actually applied the changes? GParted first lets you make a list to get a view over what happens and also because some operations can take a long time and you don't want to be sitting there for 3 hours til you can enter the next thing to change.

Comment: Oh, of course I did. I also then tried installing which also makes changes before proceeding. Installation says it proceeded smoothly, but in boot partitions are not seen as separate.